# Can not programmatically determine which TLS version my app uses

Tags: c++, ssl, tls1.2, wininet

## INTRODUCTION:

I want to programatically determine which version of TLS my application used when communicating with a server.

Application is written in C++, using WinInet.

## MY EFFORTS TO SOLVE THIS:

I have found [InternetQueryOption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385101(v=vs.85).aspx) which seemed like the solution due to [INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_CERTIFICATE_STRUCT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385328(v=vs.85).aspx) flag.

## PROBLEM:

When incorporated in my app, `InternetQueryOption` does fill in `INTERNET_CERTIFICATE_INFO` structure.

The problem is that structure's `lpszProtocolName` is empty, so I can not see which protocol is used.

Below is *MVCE* that illustrates the problem:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <WinInet.h>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "Wininet.lib")

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter HTTPS address for test" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    URL_COMPONENTS urlComp;
    ::ZeroMemory(&urlComp, sizeof(URL_COMPONENTS));
    urlComp.dwStructSize = sizeof(URL_COMPONENTS);
    urlComp.dwHostNameLength = -1;
    urlComp.dwSchemeLength = -1;
    urlComp.dwUrlPathLength = -1;

    if (!::InternetCrackUrl(argv[1], strlen(argv[1]), 0, &urlComp))
    {
        std::cout << "#0 " << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if (INTERNET_SCHEME_HTTPS != urlComp.nScheme)
    {
        std::cout << "#1 " << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    HINTERNET hIntSession = ::InternetOpen("WinInet", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);

    if (NULL == hIntSession)
    {
        std::cout << "#2 " << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::string s(strlen(argv[1]), 0);
    ::memcpy(&s[0], urlComp.lpszHostName, urlComp.dwHostNameLength);

    HINTERNET hHttpSession = ::InternetConnect(hIntSession, s.c_str(), INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, 0, 0, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, NULL);

    if (NULL == hHttpSession)
    {
        std::cout << "#3 " << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;
        ::InternetCloseHandle(hIntSession);
        return -1;
    }

    HINTERNET hHttpRequest = ::HttpOpenRequest(hHttpSession, "HEAD", NULL, 0, 0, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE, 0);

    if (NULL == hHttpRequest)
    {
        std::cout << "#4 " << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;
        ::InternetCloseHandle(hHttpSession);
        ::InternetCloseHandle(hIntSession);
        return -1;
    }

    if (!::HttpSendRequest(hHttpRequest, NULL, 0, NULL, 0)) 
    {
        std::cout << "#5 " << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;
        ::InternetCloseHandle(hHttpRequest);
        ::InternetCloseHandle(hHttpSession);
        ::InternetCloseHandle(hIntSession);
        return -1;
    }

    INTERNET_CERTIFICATE_INFO certificateInfo;
    DWORD certInfoLength = sizeof(INTERNET_CERTIFICATE_INFO);

    if (!::InternetQueryOption(hHttpRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_CERTIFICATE_STRUCT, &certificateInfo, &certInfoLength))
    {
        std::cout << "#6 " << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;
        ::InternetCloseHandle(hHttpRequest);
        ::InternetCloseHandle(hHttpSession);
        ::InternetCloseHandle(hIntSession);
        return -1;
    }

    if (certificateInfo.lpszProtocolName)
    {
        std::cout << certificateInfo.lpszProtocolName << std::endl;
        ::LocalFree(certificateInfo.lpszProtocolName);
    }

    ::InternetCloseHandle(hHttpRequest);
    ::InternetCloseHandle(hHttpSession);
    ::InternetCloseHandle(hIntSession);

    return 0;
}
```

## QUESTION:

Since this is my first time using this API with the mentioned flag, I believe I am doing something wrong.

Can you help me correct the MVCE so that I can see which version of TLS has been used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wininet has a bunch of extended functions, options and structures that are not documented as such in MSDN but are only available with a `winineti.h` (note the ending 'i') header file that should be present aside the standard wininet.h file. You don't need any external lib, they are implemented by wininet.dll (and available for linking in wininet.lib).

You will be interested specifically by the `INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_CONNECTION_INFO` option that should get you exactly what you need.

You have to pass a pointer to an `INTERNET_SECURITY_CONNECTION_INFO` struct. This struct contains a connectionInfo field of type [SecPkgContext_ConnectionInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379819.aspx) which is fully documented. This struct is in fact defined by SSPI/Schannel which is what Wininet uses internally to handle all low level protocol work.

Here is a sample code that you can add to your existing code:

```
INTERNET_SECURITY_CONNECTION_INFO connInfo = { 0 };
DWORD certInfoLength = sizeof(INTERNET_SECURITY_CONNECTION_INFO);
InternetQueryOption(hHttpRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_CONNECTION_INFO, &connInfo, &certInfoLength);

// now, connInfo.connectionInfo should contain all you need
```

Comment: Thank you, I will award bounty soon. +1

Comment: Minimal bounty period has expired, so I have awarded the bounty as promised. Thanks again. Best regards until next time!